# Help with estimating odometry using two lidar sensors with known extrinsic calibration

Tags: lie-algebra, sensor

I have a setup consisting of two lidar sensors with a known extrinsic calibration. Both lidars have messages with the same timestamps (no timedelay between them). My goal is to estimate odometry using the data from these lidars.

To achieve this, I have performed a scan-matching algorithm (ICP) and obtained transformation matrices between the consecutive pointclouds. However, I'm facing difficulties in transferring the translation and rotation frames from one lidar to another to put into some filter. The lidars are mounted on a level arm and do not have the same translation due to the Euler rigid body equation.

I would greatly appreciate your assistance in understanding how to appropriately transfer the translation and rotation frames between the lidars. Any insights, suggestions, or code examples would be highly valuable.

Thank you in advance for your help!